# What are the advantages of wavelet transform for image multiresolution analysis?

Tags: image-processing, image-analysis

Compared to gaussian pyramid and laplacian pyramid, what are the advantages and disadvantages of wavelet decomposition for multiresolution image analysis? Thank you.

Comment: Hi! This is sadly too broad. It's not clear what you've researched – and since all three terms are well-documented in literature and the internet, we must assume that you've at least tried to understand what they do, and hence, a bit on how they differ. That, however, enables you to ask a more specific question! So, please ask a **specific** question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the concise aspect of your question at the present time, a short answer is: wavelets are able to provide a critically-decimated representation (or non-redundant) of images, even orthogonal or close to. This is beneficial for applications such as compression (criticality), and for theoretical derivations (orthogonality). This can be a drawback for other practical uses.

Comment: That's right. I'm working on image segmentation and I need a scale space such that details are neglected. Wavelets are less flexible than Gaussian pyramid in this case.

Comment: Steerable pyramids could be a useful addition